# Blender Export With Armature Not Working?

Tags: animation, export, blender, fbx

I'm trying to export my character from Blender into a game engine. For some reason it imports fine without the armature but then when I export as fbx from Blender and include the armature it imports looking like a jumbled mess. I made sure to apply transformations before the export. Could it be a setting in the fbx export menu?

This really puts a damper on my project. I'll be really grateful for any help!

Here's some screenshots!

[Left: Export with Armature | Right: Without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke9FY.png)

[Loaded into Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW842.png)

[Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS6KQ.png)

[Skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJBbb.png)

[Here are the export options that I've tried playing around with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgwnp.png)

Should import in a standing position with the rig attached.